# How to display Login and Signup Page without Layout Header, Footer and Sidebar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, responsive-design

## Layout Components

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../Header";
import Sidebar from "../Sidebar";
import Footer from "../Footer";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
return (

<Header />
<Sidebar />
<main\>{children}\</main\>
<Footer /\>

);
}
```

## Routers Components

```
const routes = [
 
  {
    path: Paths.LOGIN,
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<PageLoader />}>
        <Login />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
  
  {
    path: Paths.DASHBOARD,
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<PageLoader />}>
        <Dashboard />
      </Suspense>
    ),
  },
];
export default routes;
```

I want to remove the header, footer and sidebar components for the login, signup and home Paths
How to eliminate the header

Comment: where are you using `Layout`?

Comment: You can conditionally remove them for these paths